# What is the difference between make and gcc?

Tags: gcc, makefile, compiler-construction

The last sentence in the [article](http://linuxhelp.blogspot.com/2006/04/steps-to-compile-c-c-programs-using.html) caught my eye

> [F]or C/C++ developers and
>   students interested in learning to
>   program in C/C++ rather than users of
>   Linux. This is because the compiling
>   of source code is made simple in
>   GNU/Linux by the use of the 'make'
>   command.

I have always used gcc to compile my C/C++ programs, whereas javac to compile my Java programs. I have only used make to install programs to my computer by configure/make/make install.

It seems that you can compile apparently all your programs with the command make.

**What is the difference between make and gcc?**

Comment: It should be noted that javac comprises some rudimentary dependency resolution, i.e. is also a simple make. It will recursively look for (sources of) classes used by other classes and compile them when needed, even if they were not mentioned as arguments. C compilers or linkers don't do that, partly because the connection between object file resp library on one side and the sources cannot be inferred the way they can in Java, where physical file names and paths correspond to logical class names and packages.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Well ... gcc is a compiler, make is a tool to help build programs. The difference is huge. You can never build a program purely using make; it's not a compiler. What make does it introduce a separate file of "rules", that describes how to go from source code to finished program. It then interprets this file, figures out what needs to be compiled, and calls gcc for you. This is very useful for larger projects, with hundreds or thousands of source code files, and to keep track of things like compiler options, include paths, and so on.

Comment: Make no longer needs a makefile for simple one file applications. If you have the file `application.cpp` then `make application` will build it.

Comment: @LokiAstari So there is no difference between using make or gcc for a single file? When I use gcc, I get a .out file but make gives a file with same name and no extension. What is the difference?

Comment: @Manoj: Never said there was no difference. When you run `make plop.cpp`it print out exactly what it is doing: `g++ plop.cpp -o plop` (Actual actions will very depending on your environment as make pulls settings from that as well (so its never going to be the same as invoking g++ directly)). You just don't need a `makefile` for simple situations where `make` will probably do the correct thing. But overall I think it is quite intuitive what is happening though.

Answer (score 20):

**gcc** compiles and/or links a single file. It supports multiple languages, but does not knows how to combine several source files into a non-trivial, running program - you will usually need at least two invocations of gcc (compile and link) to create even the simplest of programs.

Wikipedia page on GCC describes it as a "compiler system":

> The GNU Compiler Collection (usually shortened to GCC) is a compiler system produced by the GNU Project supporting various programming languages.

**make** is a "build tool" that invokes the compiler (which could be gcc) in a particular sequence to compile multiple sources and link them together. It also tracks dependencies between various source files and object files that result from compilation of sources and does only the operations on components that have changed since last build.

[GNUmake](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) is one popular implementation of make. The description from GNUmake is as follows:

> Make is a tool which controls the generation of executables and other non-source files of a program from the program's source files.
>
> Make gets its knowledge of how to build your program from a file called the makefile, which lists each of the non-source files and how to compute it from other files.

Answer (score 16):

gcc is a C compiler: it takes a C source file and creates machine code, either in the form of unlinked object files or as an actual executable program, which has been linked to all object modules and libraries.

make is useful for controlling the build process of a project. A typical C program consists of several modules (.c) and header files (.h). It would be time-consuming to always compile everything after you change anything, so make is designed to only compile the parts that need to be re-compiled after a change.

It does this by following rules created by the programmer. For example:

```
foo.o: foo.c foo.h
    cc -c foo.c
```

This rule tells make that the file foo.o depends on the files foo.c and foo.h, and if either of them changes, it can be built by running the command on the second line. (The above is not actual syntax: make wants the commands indented by a TAB characters, which I can't do in this editing mode. Imagine it's there, though.)

make reads its rules from a file that is usually called a Makefile. Since these files are (traditionally) written by hand, make has a lot of magic to let you shorten the rules. For example, it knows that a foo.o can be built from a foo.c, and it knows what the command to do so is. Thus, the above rule could be shortened to this:

```
foo.o: foo.h
```

A small program consisting of three modules might have a Makefile like this:

```
mycmd: main.o foo.o bar.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o mycmd main.o foo.o bar.o
foo.o: foo.h bar.h
bar.o: bar.h
```

make can do more than just compile programs. A typical Makefile will have a rule to clean out unwanted files:

```
clean:
    rm -f *.o core myapp
```

Another rule might run tests:

```
check: myapp
    ./myapp < test.input > test.output
    diff -u test.correct test.output
```

A Makefile might "build" documentation: run a tool to convert documentation from some markup language to HTML and PDF, for example.

A Makefile might have an install rule to copy the binary program it builds to wherever the user or system administrator wants it installed.

And so on. Since make is generic and powerful, it is typically used to automate the whole process from unpacking a source tarball to the point where the software is ready to be used by the user.

There is a whole lot of to learn about make if you want to learn it fully. The GNU version of make has particularly good documentation: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/ has it in various forms.

Comment: I would compare "make" and "gcc" with "git" and "ftp-transfer" in network tech.: git is like make (only updating the changed files if you want which is the common use case) and gcc like ftp (changing everything)

Answer (score 5):

[Make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) often *uses* [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/) to compile a multitude of C or C++ files.

Answer (score 4):

Make is a tool for building any complex system where there are dependancies between the various system components, by doing the minimal amount of work necessary.

If you want to find out all the things make can be used for, the [GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) is excellent.

Answer (score 4):

`make` uses a `Makefile` in the current directory to apply a set of rules to its input arguments. Make also knows some default rules so that it executes even if it doesn't find a `Makefile` (or similar) file in the current directory. The rule to execute for `cpp` files so happens to call `gcc` on many systems.

Notice that you don't call `make` with the *input* file names but rather with *rule names* which reflect *the output*. So calling `make xyz` will strive to execute rule `xyz` which by default builds a file `xyz` (for example based on a source code file `xyz.cpp`.

Answer (score 4):

`gcc` is a compiler like `javac`. You give it source files, it gives you a program.

`make` is a build tool. It takes a file that describes how to build the files in your project based on dependencies between files, so when you change one source file, you don't have to rebuild everything (like if you used a build script). `make` usually uses `gcc` to actually compile source files.

Comment: As I said in a comment to the OP's question: javac is more than just a compiler and performs dependency checks based on built-in rules (which are simple due to Java's path/name vs. package/class correspondence).

Answer (score 4):

[make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) is essentially an expert system for building code. You set up rules for how things are built, and what they depend on. Make can then look at the timestamps on all your files and figure out exactly what needs to be rebuilt at any time.

[gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/) is the "gnu compiler collection". There are many languages it supports (C, C++, Ada, etc depending on your setup), but still it is just one tool out of many that make may use to build your system.

Answer (score 3):

You can use make to compile your C and C++ programs by calling gcc or g++ in your makefile to do all the compilation and linking steps, allowing you to do all these steps with one simple command.  It is not a replacement for the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

'gcc' is the compiler - the program that actually turns the source code into an executable.  You have to tell it where the source code is, what to output, and various other things like libraries and options.

'make' is more like a scripting language for compiling programs.  It's a way to hide all the details of compiling your source (all those arguments you have to pass the compiler).  You script all of the above details once in the Makefile, so you don't have to type it every time for every file.  It will also do nifty things like only recompile source files that have been updated, and handle dependancies (if I recompile this file, I will then need to recompile THAT file.)

Answer (score 1):

The biggest difference is that make is turing complete ([Are makefiles Turing complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480950/are-makefiles-turing-complete)) while gcc is not.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the `gcc` compiler for example.
It only knows how to compile the given `.cpp` file into `.o` file given the files needed for compilation to succeed (i.e. dependencies such as .h files).

However, those dependencies create a graph. e.g., `b.o` might require `a.o` in the compilation process which means it needs to be compiled independently beforehand.

Do you, as a programer want to keep track of all those dependencies and run them in order for your target `.o` file to build?

Of course not. You want something to do that task for you.

Those are build tools - tools that help making the build process (i.e. building the artifacts like .o files) easier. One such tool is `make`.

I hope that clarifies the difference :)