# Splitting on spaces, except between certain characters

Tags: python, string-parsing

I am parsing a file that has lines such as

```
type("book") title("golden apples") pages(10-35 70 200-234) comments("good read")
```

And I want to split this into separate fields.

In my example, there are four fields: type, title, pages, and comments.

The desired result after splitting is

```
['type("book")', 'title("golden apples")', 'pages(10-35 70 200-234)', 'comments("good read")]
```

It is evident that a simple string split won't work, because it will just split at every space.
I want to split on spaces, but preserve anything in between parenthesis and quotation marks.

How can I split this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This regex should work for you `\s+(?=[^()]*(?:\(|$))`

```
result = re.split(r"\s+(?=[^()]*(?:\(|$))", subject)
```

Explanation

```
r"""
\s             # Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks)
   +              # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(?=            # Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead)
   [^()]          # Match a single character NOT present in the list “()”
      *              # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   (?:              # Match the regular expression below
                     # Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
         \(             # Match the character “(” literally
      |              # Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
         $              # Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character)
   )
)
"""
```

Comment: Nice, although it seems to be adding some extra parenthesis in the returned list (I'm not sure where they're coming from either). I'm using py3.

Comment: Try this: `re.split(r"\s+(?=[^()]*(?:\(|$))", subject)`

Comment: @Keikoku fixed it. It is because of the capturing group.

Comment: How would you extend this to support both round () and square [] brackets? Ie. ignore all strings in-between any (well matched) pair of such brackets?

Answer (score 3):

Split on `") "` and add a `)` back to each element except the last.

Answer (score 1):

I would try using a positive look-behind assertion.

```
r'(?<=\))\s+'
```

Example:

```
>>> import re
>>> result = re.split(r'(?<=\))\s+', 'type("book") title("golden apples") pages(10-35 70 200-234) comments("good read")')
>>> result
['type("book")', 'title("golden apples")', 'pages(10-35 70 200-234)', 'comments(
"good read")']
```

Comment: Would not work if there are no parentheses in the input text such as `test test test`.

Comment: The question already defined the format.  test test test is not a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Let me add a non-regex solution:

```py
line = 'type("book") title("golden apples") pages(10-35 70 200-234) comments("good read")'

count = 0 # Bracket counter
last_break = 0 # Index of the last break
parts = []
for j,char in enumerate(line):
    if char is '(': count += 1
    elif char is ')': count -= 1
    elif char is ' ' and count is 0:
        parts.append(line[last_break:(j)])
        last_break = j+1
parts.append(line[last_break:]) # Add last element
parts = tuple(p for p in parts if p) # Convert to tuple and remove empty

for p in parts:
    print(p)
```

In general there are certain things you [cannot do with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983115/are-perl-regexes-turing-complete), and there can be serious performance penalties (especially for lookahead and lookbehind) which can cause them not to be the best solution for a certain problem.

Also; I thought I'd mention the [`pyparsing`](https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module which can be used to create custom text parsers.

Comment: It's been 8 years since I had initially asked the question but I would agree, using a parser is better than regex especially for things like parentheses and quotation matching.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another non-regex solution to split a string between spaces except when a sub-string is between parenthesis.

```
    file_line = 'type("book") title("golden apples") pages(10 - 35 70 200 - 234) comments("good read")'
    list_of_params = []
    param = ''

    between_parenthesis = False
    for character in file_line:
        if between_parenthesis:
            if character == ')':
                between_parenthesis= False
        else:
            if character == '(':
                between_parenthesis= True

            if character == ' ':
                list_of_params.append(param)
                param = ''
                continue

        param += character

    list_of_params.append(param)
    print(list_of_params)
```

result:

```
    ['type("book")', 'title("golden apples")', 'pages(10 - 35 70 200 - 234)', 'comments("good read")']
```