# Split string if separator is not in-between two characters

Tags: python

I want to write a script that reads from a csv file and splits each line by comma except any commas in-between two specific characters.

In the below code snippet I would like to split line by commas except the commas in-between two `$`s.

```
line = "$abc,def$,$ghi$,$jkl,mno$"

output = line.split(',')

for o in output:
   print(o)
```

How do I write `output = line.split(',')` so that I get the following terminal output?

```
~$ python script.py
$abc,def$
$ghi$
$jkl,mno$
```

Comment: Take a look at [the regular expression syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax). Specifically, it seems you are looking for the negative look-ahead/look-behind operators

Comment: Check out: [Splitting on spaces, except between certain characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644784/splitting-on-spaces-except-between-certain-characters) and customize solutions for comma and $.

Comment: Your requirements and expected output describe 2 different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a regular expression:

In re, the `(?<!\$)` will match a character not immediately following a `$`.

Similarly, a `(?!\$)` will match a character not immediately before a dollar.

The `|` character cam match multiple options. So to match a character where either side is not a `$` you can use:

```
expression = r"(?<!\$),|,(?!\$)"
```

Full program:

```
import re
expression = r"(?<!\$),|,(?!\$)"
print(re.split(expression, "$abc,def$,$ghi$,$jkl,mno$"))
```

Comment: Lookbehind and lookahead is the perfect solution for this problem

Answer (score 1):

One solution (maybe not the most elegant but it will work) is to replace the string `$,$` with something like `$,,$` and then split `,,`. So something like this

```
output = line.replace('$,$','$,,$').split(',,')
```

Using regex like [mousetail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6333444/mousetail) suggested is the more elegant and robust solution but requires knowing regex (not that anyone KNOWS regex)

Comment: This is the opposite of what op wants, he wants to split when *not* surrounded by `$`

Comment: That's not what it looks like from the expected output. It looks like they want to split lines when in between $ signs

Comment: You are correct. The question is unclear

Comment: I'll edit so it becomes more clear

Answer (score 1):

Try [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```py
import re

line = "$abc,def$,$ghi$,$jkl,mno$"

output = re.findall(r"\$(.*?)\$", line)

for o in output:
    print('$'+o+'$')
```

```
$abc,def$
$ghi$
$jkl,mno$
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you can identify a character that is not used in that line:

```
c = chr(max(map(ord, line)) + 1)
```

Then, you can proceed as follows:

```
line.replace('$,$', f'${c}$').split(c)
```

Here is your example:

```
>>> line = '$abc,def$,$ghi$,$jkl,mno$'
>>> c = chr(max(map(ord, line)) + 1)
>>> result = line.replace('$,$', f'${c}$').split(c)
>>> print(*result, sep='\n')
$abc,def$
$ghi$
$jkl,mno$
```