# Check if a given regex will match anything

Tags: regex, string, perl

Is it possible to check if a given regular expression will match any string?  Specifically, I'm looking for a function `matchesEverything($regex)` that returns true iff `$regex` will match any string.

I suppose that this is equivalent to asking, "given a regex `r`, does there exist a string that doesn't match `r`?" and I don't think this is solvable without placing bounds on the set of "all strings".  I.e., if I assume the strings will never contain "blahblah", then I can simply check if `r` matches "blahblah".  But what if there are no such bounds?  I'm wondering if this problem can be solved checking if the regex `r` is equivalent to `.*`.

Comment: I believe this is equivalent to the [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).  It may not be possible to write an algorithm to determine if an arbitrary regex is equivalent to `.*`

Comment: Regexes with lookarounds and backrefs, but no code interpolation, should be a subset of or equal to context sensitive grammars. Deciding these languages is not Turing complete, therefore this question shouldn't be equivalent to the halting problem. *If*, given a CSG, we can produce a string of this language by substituting the rules, then we may apply a forbidden substitution, thus producing a string that is not in our language. Sadly I don't know whether this is the case, and I wouldn't be able to sketch a proof of this.

Comment: This is called the "Emptiness Problem", and is decidable for DFAs/NFAs (i.e. regexes without backreferences/lookarounds) http://www.cs.miami.edu/~ogihara/csc527/new04-1.pdf

For regexes with backrefs (context sensitive grammars), the emptiness problem is undecidable. (I can't find a proof right now, but it's frequently mentioned in the literature)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but hopefully explains a little why a simple answer is hard to come by:

First, the term 'regex' is a bit murky, so just to clarify, we have:

- "Strict" regular expressions, which are equivalent to deterministic finite automatons (DFAs).
- Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCREs), which add a bunch of bells and whistles such as lookaheads, backreferences, etc. These are implemented in other languages too, such as Python and Java.
- Actual Perl regular expressions, which can get even more crazy, including arbitrary Perl code, via the `?{...}` construct.

I think this problem is solvable for strict regular expressions. You just construct the corresponding DFA and search that graph to see if there's any path to a non-accept state. But that doesn't help for 'real world' regex, which is usually PCRE.

I don't think PCRE is Turing-complete (though I don't know - see this question, too: [Are Perl regexes turing complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983115/are-perl-regexes-turing-complete)). If it were, then I think as Jim Garrison commented, this is basically the halting problem.
That said, it's not easy to transform them into a DFA, either, making the above method useless...

I don't have an answer for PCREs, but be aware that the aforementioned constructs (backreferences, etc) would make it pretty hard, I imagine. Though I hesitate to say "impossible."

A genuine Perl regex with `?{...}` in it is definitely Turing-complete, so there be dragons, and I think you're out of luck.

Comment: great reply. you've reinforced what i was thinking. for the use case that i'm addressing, any actual perl regular expressions would be what i care about.  pretty much anything where `eval{ 'xx' =~ m/$regex/i; }` results in a successful eval.