# How to count img tags which has no alt tags by using regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

How to count `img` tags which has **no alt**  tags in by using regex?

```
 MatchCollection AltTag = Regex.Matches(
     strIn,
     "<img .*? />", 
     RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline
 );
 lblImgTags.Text = "We found " + AltTag.Count.ToString() + " images on this website ";
```

I am counting `img` tags like this but how can I count `img` tags which have no alt tags?

Comment: Regex is the last thing you'd ideally want to use for this. Why not use jQuery and read the string as a DOM?

Comment: this may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags regex is not great at parsing html

Comment: @OliverRadini I was looking for that but couldn't find it :D

Comment: haha it seems like a SO classic

Comment: Use `//img[not(@alt)]` XPath with HtmlAgilityPack. Or with regex: [`<img\b(?![^<]*\salt=)[^<]*>`](https://regex101.com/r/gN5bN6/2).

Comment: Why have you tagged `jquery`? You can't use jQuery in C# code, and your example is very clearly C# code. Why have you tagged `javascript`? I've removed the irrelevant tags for you.

Answer (score 2):

> How to count img tags which has no alt tags by using regex

You can't. You [cannot use regular expressions to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/157247). You may think you have a sufficiently-contained use case that you can. So have I. I was wrong, and with respect, I'm afraid you are as well.

Use an HTML parser to parse HTML. There are several, such as NSoup, which is a .Net port of the excellent Java JSoup library. But that is just one option of many.

Comment: Nice. Everyone posts this but there is also [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1758162/2729609) to this post that goes into theory. The comments are very interesting. Currently: I'm not sure that is it impossible to parse HTML using Regex. Maybe: It's a pain - but possible.

Comment: @Verarind: No, it's impossible (with **just** a single regex). Regex can play a *part* in parsing HTML, but cannot parse it. HTML is a non-regular language. Good link, btw.

Comment: As I told: I'm not sure. But there is a comment that perl regex engine is turing complete - this might be enough to parse HTML. The question was about C# regex engine. Maybe is has also enough power to parse HTML - I don't know. I would not use Regex to parse HTML but it sounds that some engine are able to do that.

Comment: @Verarind: Well, you can doubt it if you like, but it's like doubting the Earth is an oblate spheroid. :-) Not even Perl, certainly not C#. Why? Not least because HTML has all kinds of special case rules. If you doubt it, [read all about it](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing). A really smart engine might get you 90% there, but 10% is a lot. Re Perl and turing complete, [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983115/are-perl-regexes-turing-complete).

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?=.*<img)(?!.*alt).*
```

Would be the regex

Comment: I used http://refiddle.com/refiddles/563a041175622d334e150000 to test it, but I'm really sorry it doesn't work for you

Answer (score 0):

To just count, try this with use of lookahead. [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/oU2cR3/1)

```
<img\s(?![^>]*\balt\s*=)
```

Or a bit more expensive to match the tags. [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/oU2cR3/3)

```
<img\s(?:(?!\balt\s*=)[^>])+>
```

Together with your `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`

Comment: [As I said, you can't reliably parse HTML with regular expressions.](https://regex101.com/r/oU2cR3/4) Those examples (at the end) were just three that came to mind in 30 seconds or so.