# Install gccgo for testing Protocol Buffers 3 along with Go

Tags: go, gcc

I'm trying to install `gccgo` for testing Protocol Buffers 3 with Golang...I have to confess that I'm back to dev after 8 years off (and I'm not a native speaker) so, thank you for your indulgence. Thank you :)

So, After a few readings, I decided to start from the README of this repo: https://github.com/golang/protobuf

## 1st bullet point: checked!

The last version os the protocol buffer is installed on my Mac ( `protobuf-cpp-3.11.4.tar.gz`
from my understanding) https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.11.4

```
$ ls $GOBIN
dlv*           gocode*        godef*         gopkgs*        protoc-gen-go*
go-outline*    gocode-gomod*  golint*        goreturns*
```

## 2nd bullet point: Here I've spent a couple of hours ... without success :/

> Of course, install the Go compiler and tools from https://golang.org/ See 
>   https://golang.org/doc/install for details or, if you are using gccgo, follow the instructions at https://golang.org/doc/install/gccgo

My understanding is that I need to install `gccgo` which is a branch of the gcc compiler. Then I've read that `gccgo` is just in fact a custom build of the gcc compiler configured with the `--enable-languages=c,c++,go` option ( src https://golang.org/doc/install/gccgo ) ... so why is there a special branch on the repos and where it is? (https://gcc.gnu.org/git.html)  I

I just give up to try to download the gccgo branch from the git repository and find a svn repo:

```
$ svn checkout svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/branches/gccgo gccgo`
gccgo$ ./configure --enable-languages=c,c++,go
...
configure: error: Building GCC requires GMP 4.2+, MPFR 3.1.0+ and MPC 0.8.0+.
Try the --with-gmp, --with-mpfr and/or --with-mpc options to specify
their locations.  Source code for these libraries can be found at
their respective hosting sites as well as at
<https://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/>.  See also
<http://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html> for additional info.  If
you obtained GMP, MPFR and/or MPC from a vendor distribution package,
make sure that you have installed both the libraries and the header
files.  They may be located in separate packages.
```

So, I downloaded `gmp-6.2.0.tar.lz` from https://gmplib.org/ which leads me to install `lzip`before untaring the archive

```
$ brew install lzip
$ lunzip gmp-6.2.0.tar.lz
$ tar - xvzf gmp-6.2.0.tar
$ cd gmp-6.2.0
gmp-6.2.0$ ./configure
gmp-6.2.0$ make
gmp-6.2.0$ make install
gmp-6.2.0$ make check ( a few warnings but every test have been passed successfully )
```

Then, installed mpfr-3.1.6.tar.gz

```
$ tar -xvzf mpfr-3.1.6.tar.gz
$ cd mpfr-3.1.6
mpfr-3.1.6$ ./configure
mpfr-3.1.6$ ./make
mpfr-3.1.6$ ./make install
```

... and try again

```
gccgo$ ./configure --enable-languages=c,c++,go
...
The following requested languages could not be built: go
Supported languages are: c,brig,c,c++,d,fortran,lto,objc,obj-c++
```

## Lastly

I'm not sure about the directory they are talking about in the last step...

> Build the Go samples in this directory with "make go". This creates the following executable 
>   files in the current directory:
>   add_person_go      list_people_go

`make` works with `gcc` to introduces a separate file of "rules", that describes how to go from source code to finished program, interprets this file, figures out what needs to be compiled, and calls `gcc`. ( source https://stackoverflow.com/a/768379/1216281 ). So, if gcc it not compiled properly, it can't work.

```
protocolbuffer$ ls
add_person.go        add_person_test.go   addressbook.proto    list_people_test.go
add_person.go.txt    addressbook.pb.go    list_people.go
protocolbuffer$ make go
make: *** No rule to make target `go'.  Stop.
```

Extra tech. infos if neeeded :

```
~$ echo $GOPATH
/Users/me/Dev/Go/golib:/Users/me/Dev/Go/code
```

```
$GOBIN is /Users/me/Dev/Go/golib/bin
$ echo $GOBIN
/Users/me/Dev/Go/golib/bin
```

Comment: Could you clarify what is your "ultimate goal"? Do you want to use `go` to play with protobuf or you specifically want to use gccgo for compiling  *.go files?

Comment: Hi @Ilya, I think I mix up with this procedure thinking that `gccgo` and Go compiling tools were both needed. So, I understand that protoc-gen-go (the plugin part of protobuf) just need to find the Go compiling tool (already installed with Golang) by checking the $GOBIN directory. Then, I compile the `.proto`files by using `protoc`(the compiler part of protobuf) with options `--go_out=DEST_FOLDER *.proto` and I'm done, right ? ( It reminds me of the old days with Java RMI)

Comment: Yes, basically if you need to compile some protobuf example in golang you need to do two main steps: generate `*.pb.go` files using `protoc` and then compile the example using `go build` (the standard build tool)

Answer (score 4):

In order to compile protobufs in go, you need to have `go compiler` and the following packages

```
go get github.com/golang/protobuf
go get github.com/golang/protobuf/proto
```

If your GOPATH is included in your PATH env, you should be able to execute `protoc` binary from your terminal.

Let's try a simple example. You define a `protobuf` schema first, which represents some object. It can look something like

```
syntax="proto3";

package main;

message Person {
      string name = 1;
      int32 age = 2;
}
```

> person.proto

Next step is to compile it into go source code, using the `protoc`

```
protoc --go_out=. *.proto
```

It will generate a go source code file represnting your proto `message` inm a file `person.pb.go`.

Let's see how we can use it in our `main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"
)

func main() {

    p := &Person{
        Name: "John Doe",
        Age:  30,
    }

    data, err := proto.Marshal(p)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("marshaling error: %v", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

  fmt.Printf("our raw protobuf object looks like: %+v\nits type is %T\n", data, data)

  // let's unmarshal it (from byte array) to an object we can use as Person
    newP := &Person{}
    err = proto.Unmarshal(data, newP)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("unmarshaling error: %v", err)
        os.Exit(1)
  }

  // now we can use our unmarshaled data as a struct
  fmt.Printf("newP name: %v\nnewP age: %v\nnewP type: %T\n", newP.GetName(), newP.GetAge(), newP)

}
```

Let's run it

```
→ go run .
our raw protobuf object looks like: [10 8 74 111 104 110 32 68 111 101 16 30]
its type is []uint8
newP name:  John Doe
newP age:  30
newP type: *main.Person
```

You can look at the auto-generated source code in person.pb.go. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for sharing this clear example. I've found what I was missing in between, but it still valuable, thank you for that :)